# Using WebClient.UploadStringAsync with GET data

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm trying to use WebClient.UploadStringAsync method to send some data to server. It works fine when I send POST data, but when using GET, it throws me an error "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
Here is my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String data = "param1=value1&param2=value2";
client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://somesite.com"), "GET", data);
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: use `client.DownloadStringAsync(url + params);` as `GET` is not an 'upload'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use **UploadStringAsync** for `GET`. There is [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) designed specifically for that.
2. Don't use **WebClient** because it is bound to the UI thread. Use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: If i want to upload my data object and want to response from the server than what should me use ?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading data for a GET breaks convention. 
You might also want to take a look at HTTPClient which you can install via NuGet.